# converting excel to pdf using office 2007 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in asp.net 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, xls

I am trying to convert an excel(.xls) file to .pdf format using c#, .net framework 2, with office 2007 and Add-in installed.

With the help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769246/xls-to-pdf-conversion-inside-net ,  I got it working successfully on my development computer.

However, I keep getting problem on live web server.  it seems to keep 'freezing' at line

```
wbk.ExportAsFixedFormat(fileFormat, outputFileName,
                missing, missing, missing,
                missing, missing, missing,
                missing);
```

Am I missing something at our web server?  we already installed office and add-in 2007.  still doesn't work.
something to do with 'security' issues?

Comment: Whatever "user" owns the thread pool that your website is running under will need write access to where ever, on your server, you are writing.

Comment: thanks for the info.
I just tried to save the .xls file as another NewName.xls file using
xbk.SaveAs(sOutputFileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, missing, missing, missing, missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing)
and it worked just fine.  so i think it must be something else that causing it not be able to create PDF format file.